# Automated way to write a wrapper and interface for dependency injection of third party libraries?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, wrapper

I'm using a third party library class `Foo` that has several public methods and properties that my class uses as a dependency.

I want to test my class and mock the `Foo` object, but it does not have an interface.  So I was thinking, I could inherit the class in a class of my own, extract an interface, and voila!  I would have an injectable interface.

...but of course there are complications.  `Foo` has a bunch of public fields.  These can't go into an interface, so I'd have to write property wrappers for the fields.  It's annoying.

Is there an automated way to do this?  I have ReSharper, but there doesn't seem to be a way to automagically do this, which means I'm writing a lot of tedious code.

Comment: Are the methods you're mocking `virtual`? If so, you can use something like Rhino Mocks' `PartialMock`. You'd be able to override/stub/mock the methods and have access to the public fields.

Comment: Hah of course not... this library was not designed to be extensible at all, and I don't think the authors ever wrote a unit test... sigh...

Comment: How about this? Create a wrapper that exposes the methods as `virtual` and then use `PartialMock`! What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: Moq.  Seems to do everything I want it to do.

Comment: I haven't used Moq, but it looks like you can do partial mocks using the `callbase` property. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769928/using-moq-to-mock-only-some-methods So you can create a wrapper, expose methods as `virtual` and then use a a partial.

Comment: If you are mocking your Foo class, what is the expected behavior of the mock methods calls made by your tested class?

Comment: Mainly just to test that they were invoked, and returning dummy responses without kicking off a process that was out of scope for the unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a wrapper class that uses and interface you have designed that only expose what you need from Foo.

So for example:

```
class MyFooWrapper : IFoo
{
   private Foo _foo;
    // methods exposed by IFoo
 }
```

You could take further by making MyFooWrapper an abstract class to contain the properties and any other base functionality but don't put Foo in there , instead have a class that inherits the foo wrapper .

Answer (score 3):

You should split your class under test into two separate classes. One class that contains the (business) logic that you need to test, and a second class that acts as an adapter to the external dependency. This adapter class should implement an interface and the logic class should depend on that interface. This interface should *not* mimic the API of the external dependency, but the interface should be defined in the application's needs. By doing this you achieve that you:

- adhere to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), because currently your class under tests has two responsibilities.
- adhere to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) by placing the new adapter behind an abstraction. This prevents your application from having to take a dependency on the external tool (only your composition root needs to depend on it), which makes your application more testable, and more maintainable.
- adhere to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), that states that interfaces should be narrow and defined for the role they participate in.

What you'll end up with is an adapter class that is tightly coupled to the external library. This adapter will transform an incoming call to something that it can send on to the external library. This adapter can't be tested in isolation, and if testing is important, you'll probably need integration tests for this (depending on how the external library functions). Important to say is that you don't have to test that the external library works, but you probably still want to test the correctness of the adapter class.

Comment: What two responsibilities do you see the class having?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: It contains both (business) logic and it is the adapter. Those are two different responsibilities.

Comment: Hmm... so you are talking about an adapter, where I was talking about a wrapper.  Are these synonymous in your mind?  I would think a wrapper has one responsibility: to directly translate the business logic of an external class.  I wonder if we're talking about the same thing or different here?

Comment: Yes, an adapter is a wrapper, but with the specific feature that it really 'adapts' from the application domain to the adapted components , instead of just mimicking the interface of the adapted component, which would simply be wrapping.